# Compare old document height to new document height using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please i want to compare my `div` with `id = message` old document height to new document height.
If there is a difference, then it should scroll to bottom automatically, else nothing should happen. I wish to do this in pure javascript.

This is what i have so far but confused on how to get things done.I know there is surely a way but not succeeding.

```
    function Scroll(){

            var elem = document.getElementById('message');
            elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;

        }
```

Thanks for quick response.

Comment: So you want it that if your `message` is larger than your *entire* window, scroll to the bottom of the message automatically?

Comment: That is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a one-step 'jump' scroll, you can use 
`window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)`:

```js
function Scroll() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('message');
  if (elem.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight) {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
}

Scroll();
```

```html
<div id="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam non lorem efficitur eros fringilla vestibulum vel in nisl. Nullam porttitor auctor euismod. Duis efficitur eu ipsum sit amet porta. Etiam sagittis velit id urna ultricies, id semper nisi
  ornare. Donec ullamcorper orci dui, et eleifend metus dictum quis. Donec libero nisl, sodales at odio sit amet, dignissim egestas enim. Pellentesque consectetur erat eget tellus vehicula efficitur. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in
  faucibus. Vivamus suscipit, lacus id maximus fermentum, erat velit venenatis diam, ac viverra mi erat in nunc. Aenean eu urna dignissim, elementum dui quis, elementum eros. Duis eleifend metus sed risus sodales efficitur. Fusce sit amet ipsum et magna
  luctus tristique. Mauris vitae libero et odio aliquet rhoncus. Donec sed dui ac massa volutpat elementum. Nullam et nibh sit amet nisl accumsan placerat. Morbi at tortor non metus tempor euismod. Nam eget mi at diam sodales tristique non et lacus. Aenean
  non nunc imperdiet, consectetur nibh egestas, semper orci. Sed tristique sem odio. Phasellus ultrices lorem venenatis purus pellentesque, in vestibulum augue congue. Vestibulum eu maximus mauris. Nulla facilisi. Etiam in semper velit, nec accumsan nunc.
  Curabitur vel fermentum velit, quis blandit velit. Cras eu scelerisque est. Nunc vel dictum ipsum. Maecenas eleifend efficitur metus nec auctor. Donec ut enim hendrerit, gravida urna eu, hendrerit mauris. Proin orci nulla, tristique vitae pharetra ut,
  blandit eget erat. Sed lectus mauris, fringilla ut felis nec, feugiat faucibus sapien. Morbi est felis, suscipit at tellus pharetra, interdum gravida lectus. Praesent molestie euismod sagittis. Sed blandit dictum magna, ac ornare elit dignissim eget.
  Morbi varius libero sit amet est fermentum, id convallis quam interdum. Praesent posuere eros id dignissim euismod. Sed urna quam, facilisis quis lacinia sit amet, pellentesque et lacus. Vivamus faucibus sagittis dictum. Duis posuere, ipsum elementum
  molestie pulvinar, elit odio lobortis ipsum, non finibus velit urna vel neque. Aliquam vehicula augue non sapien fringilla varius. Suspendisse at pellentesque nibh. Vestibulum sollicitudin lacus quis lectus hendrerit venenatis at ut lacus. Donec condimentum
  fringilla tellus id bibendum. Donec facilisis elit erat, at varius velit dictum vel. Vivamus bibendum tincidunt justo, lobortis euismod tortor semper vel. Morbi non felis tortor. Aliquam vitae elementum ligula. Praesent sem risus, gravida vitae neque
  iaculis, interdum maximus nibh. Etiam eu ullamcorper dui. Etiam mauris lectus, bibendum quis semper eget, egestas a nunc. Maecenas maximus pharetra mi id egestas.</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Obsidian Age,it isn't scrolling in my case. I think i need to make it clearer.I am receiving dynamic data from mysql database and want my `div` containing this data to scroll to the bottom of the `div` if new data is added. Thanks